# How can $a^T(b-xa) = 0 $ means $xa^{T}a = a^Tb$?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I was watching [gilbert strang lectures on the projection matrix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_Ac6KiQ1t0&list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D&index=15), at 5.17 he wrote that:

$a^T(b-xa) = 0 $

That means:

$xa^{T}a = a^Tb$

how can we write this expression?

In my opinion isn't it should be: $ a^Txa = a^Tb $ ?

Actually I am not good at linear algebra, so I know the question may be silly.

Comment: Can you define $x$, $b$, and $a$ in terms of their dimension?  No one wants to watch your video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and then $a^T.xa=xa^T.a=x\|a\|^2$

Answer (score 1):

Because, If you heard carefully,(at 2:50) he says that $\textbf{p}$ is scalar multiple of $\textbf{a}$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$

$$\textbf{p} = x.\textbf{a} , x \in \mathbb{R} , \textbf{a}^T. (x\textbf{a}) = x( \textbf{a}^{T}.\textbf{a})$$